# Update a mysql table column with sum of joined table columns value?

Tags: mysql

Order Table

```
Id
OrderDate
Total
```

Item Table

```
Id
Price
Quantity
OrderId (fkey -> order.Id)
```

Order has many Items.

In mysql SQL, is there a way to update `order.total`, so that it's the total sum of the product  `item.price` and `item.quantity` for each item?

That is-

```
orders.each:
   order.items.each:
      sum += item.price * item.quantity;
   order.total = sum;
```

I could write a simple script for this, but I'd like to learn how to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can do this with an `update`/`join`.  You need to aggregate the `items` to get the total and then join the result back to `orders` to do the update:

```
update orders o join
       (select i.orderid, sum(i.price * i.quantity) as total
        from items i
        group by i.orderid
       ) oi
       on o.orderid = oi.orderid
    set o.total = oi.total;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this! I think though `on i.orderid = oi.orderid` should read `on o.id = oi.orderid`